# Emgu - GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures returns null every time

Tags: opencv, emgucv

I am using Emgu (an OpenCV C# wrapper), and every time I try to get a HomographyMatrix from the GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures method, it comes back null. The GetHomographyMatrixFromMatchedFeatures method comments state "Recover the homography matrix 
using RANDSAC. If the matrix cannot be recovered, return null."

I have valid matched features.

I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to recover the matrix. Any clues?

Thanks.

Comment: Any luck with this? Have you solve it? If yes, can you tell us how?

Comment: Never solved this problem... I have since moved on from the project

Comment: Have you checked the lenght of your featureS? It must be >= 4